# Cannot deploy program onto solana mainnet

Tags: solana-program, program, deploy

First of all, it's super slow when deploy(anchor deploy) my program to mainnet, I got error:

```
Blockhash expired. 4 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 3 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 2 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 1 retries remaining
⠉   9.6% | Sending 24/176 transactions [block height 237840819; re-sign in 162 blocks]
```

solana cluster-version: 1.17.25
solana --version: 1.17.25

I try to update solana-cli to the latest version: 1.17.28,  problem still exists.

But when I deploy the same code to devnet, its fast and works fine.

Why this issue happen and how to fix it? Thanx